# Selenium page_source does not return modified DOM tree

Tags: javascript, python, dom, selenium-webdriver

I want to figure out the changes before and after applying an addon like NoScript/ghostery to a certain webpage. NoScript/ghostery blocks trackers' and advertisers' scripts and remove them from DOM tree (as an example I checked it 'http://a.visualrevenue.com/vrs.js' while surfed cnn.com before and after 'enabling' NoScript in Firefox). However, 'http://a.visualrevenue.com/vrs.js' is still there if I dump DOM tree using selenium's browser.get_source. I am using the following code in the process:

```
import pickle
from selenium import webdriver

fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile(../<extension/addons/>)
browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp)
browser.get("http://www.cnn.com")
html_source = browser.page_source
f = open("cnn.p", "wb")
pickle.dump(html_source, f)
```

selenium's get_source get source documentations says that it gets modified (in my case modified by NoScript) DOM tree but I couldn't figured out that if this happens. I would appreciate if anyone could comment on how to get modified (by an addon) DOM tree using selenium or any automated tool.

Comment: edit: line # 3 was replaced with more generic format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After tried several ways, finally solved my problem. Instead of using webdriver.page_source (outputs 'html source'), I used webdriver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.outerHTML") to  dump rendered HTML.